# How can I pass a pointer to the constructor of the object when instantiating the object with push_back()?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to achieve the following, a single object of class manager is trying to create many objects of class worker. manager object is passing it self as a reference to the worker objects, so that the worker objects can change their behavior based on the state of the manager object.

```
class manager; 

class worker{
public:
  worker(manager &boss);

};

class manager{

  public:
  unsigned int currentMethod = 5;

  manager(int numofWorkers);
};
```

The way I am trying implement this is by, when the constructor for manager is invoked, I create a vector of workers and I try to push_back(this) aka manager object.

```
manager::manager(int numOfWorkers){

  std::vector<worker> manyWorkers;

  for(int i = 0; i < numOfWorkers;i++){
    manyWorkers.push_back(this);
  }
}

worker::worker(manager &boss){
  std::cout << "Current method is " << boss.currentMethod << std::endl; 
}
```

The way this code is called is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  manager manag;

  return 0;
}
```

It turns out that push_back(this) does not pass "this" to the constructor of the class although push_back() invokes the constructor. I have also tried manyWorkers(this).push_back which does not work either.

How can I pass a pointer to the constructor of the manyWorkers object when instantiating the object with push_back()?

I am confused as to what to call what I am trying to achieve and have not been able to search for a solution.

Comment: If you want your container to manage polymorphic references, you will need to redefine your container so that it manages pointers, or better yet, shared pointers to the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `emplace_back` to invoke a constructor with parameters:

```
manyWorkers.emplace_back(*this);
```

Notice it should be `*this`, because the constructor you are invoking (`worker(manager &boss);`) takes the `manager` parameter by reference, not as pointer.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem. I can accept this answer in two minutes.

Comment: Note that `emplace_back()` is only in C++11 and later.  In earlier versions (and newer), `push_back(*this)` or `push_back(worker(*this))` should work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the useful emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than simply storing `this` in the vector (which seems like you want to store workers), you'll need to instantiate a new worker and then push that back onto the vector.

```
std::vector<*worker> manyWorkers; // Use * since we are dynamically allocating
for(int i = 0; i < numOfWorkers;i++){
    worker* myWorker = new worker(this);
    manyWorkers.push_back(myWorker);
}
```